# Why doesn't Scala "handle" ClassTags automatically?

Tags: scala, reflection

Class tags seem to be really easy to use, however, is it not mathematically possible to always reliably automatically insert the `ClassTag` boilerplate in at least some scenarios if not all? Consider this example:

```
def foo[T: ClassTag] = {
    val cls = classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
    val myList: Seq[T] = parseList(rawJson, cls) // let's assume parseList a library method that needs to work with a Class instance (e.g. RestFB's fetchConnnection)
    ...
}
```

why wouldn't Scala let me write instead:

```
def foo[T] = {
    val cls = classOf[T]
    val myList: Seq[T] = parseList(rawJson, cls) // let's assume parseList a library method that needs to work with a Class instance (e.g. RestFB's fetchConnnection)
    ...
}
```

...and transform the latter to the former automatically?

Is there a technical reason for this, e.g. the desirability of class tags cannot always be reliably determined by the compiler/reflection library? Or it's purely a conscious design choice to keep this explicit? For example to encourage the programmer to avoid the need to use class tags in the first place for a cleaner design and better performance, even if it's known that in many cases it's not possible?

**P.S.** I'm *not* asking why Scala doesn't (nor proposing it should) add the `ClassTag` magic to *every* method definition with a generic type parameter; I'm merely asking why it couldn't be done automatically when it's *needed/unavoidable*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax:

```
def foo[T: ClassTag] = ...
```

in fact is a shorthand for this one:

```
def foo[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = ...
```

This means if `ClassTag[T]` were supplied for every generic type parameter, then *every* function would have additonal hidden parameter, or even several.

This is of course completely undesirable. One of the most prominent downsides of this approach is nearly ruined Java interoperability when using generics:

```java
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.foo<Integer>(ClassTag.apply(Integer.class));
```

Imagine more advanced generic methods and parameters. And this is only for the ability to match on generic type, which is almost never needed.

Calling Java generic methods would also be ambigous. Which method should be called here:

```
val jc = new JavaClass
jc.foo[Int]()
```

if `JavaClass` is defined like this:

```java
public class JavaClass {
    public <T> void foo() { ... }
    public <T> void foo(ClassTag<T> ct) { ... }
}
```

?

Of course, if Java supported reified generics, everything would be different...

Comment: "supplied for every generic type parameter" — but I didn't say the transform should happen every time... only when it's unavoidable.

Comment: @ErikAllik, that means very volatile API. Suppose you change your code which previously didn't require a `ClassTag` so it started to depend on it. Then all users of your API could potentially break, and you won't even notice. You can even break your own code, when your generic method overrides another method - suddenly it will stop overriding its parent. Moreover, this means that you don't have complete control over signatures of your methods. I certainly wouldn't like that.

Comment: OK, that's a good point; I'll just wait a little bit more to see if anybody else can come up with some additional reasonings.